# Can you trigger a Google Cloud Functions via firebase event without a server?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I will be implementing an elastic search index alongside my firebase application so that it can better support ad-hoc full text searches and geo searches.  Thus, I need to sync firebase data to the elastic search index and all the examples require a server process that listens for firebase events.

e.g. https://github.com/firebase/flashlight

However, it would be great if I can just have a google cloud function triggered by an insert in a firebase node.  I see that google cloud functions has various triggers: pub sub, storage and direct... can any of these bridge to a firebase node event without an intermediate server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe **Cloud Functions for Firebase** are what you are looking for.
Here are a few links:

- [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)
- [Intro video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vr0Gfvp5v1A)
- [Google Cloud Functions and Firebase (Google Cloud Next '17)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNR9El3XWYo)

Comment: Yup I think that's it - they must have just released that recently?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey yes - video is from yesterday. I've updated my answer to include the talk at Google Next :)

Answer (score 11):

*firebaser here*

We just released [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). This allows you to run JavaScript functions on Google's servers in response to Firebase events (such as database changes, users signing in and much more).

Comment: cool, will check it out - do you have a link to the slides?  I don't see it in the github readme

Comment: Would love to see this implemented, along with an official way to read/write to DataStore from a Firebase web app (long term db storage when realtime isn't needed)

Comment: Looks like there'll be something interesting announced at [GCN 17](https://cloudnext.withgoogle.com/schedule#target=google-cloud-functions-and-firebase-e201ac5d-ed02-47a9-af78-33e23368a26c). :)

Comment: @Frank do we have any other option if our server don't support Npm

Comment: Cloud Functions run on Google's servers, not on yours.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Any info on connecting to external/local services? For example I'd like to POST to an App Engine API endpoint I have running locally when a property is updated

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem with that would be. But if you're having problems, open a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can trigger a Google Cloud Functions via firebase event without a server.
As per documents,Firebase allows for example you can send notifications using a cloud function when a user write into firebase database.

For that, I had to write a javascript as below

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/articles/{articleId}')
        .onWrite(event => {

        // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
        var eventSnapshot = event.data;
        var str1 = "Author is ";
        var str = str1.concat(eventSnapshot.child("author").val());
        console.log(str);

        var topic = "android";
        var payload = {
            data: {
                title: eventSnapshot.child("title").val(),
                author: eventSnapshot.child("author").val()
            }
        };

        // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
        return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
                // contents of response.
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            });
        });
```